# bash - color escapes codes

Tags: linux, bash, colors, ansi-escape

I have a script that uses escape codes to highlight text matches in its output. All is good except when the output is piped to `less`, which prints the escape codes

e.g.

```
$ echo -e "\033[31m -- Hello World! -- \033[m"
 -- Hello World! --
```

Piped to `less`:

```
$ echo -e "\033[31m -- Hello World! -- \033[m" | less
ESC[31m -- Hello World! -- ESC[m
```

I was wondering how other tools like `ls`, `grep`, etc are able to output in color yet it looks fine when piped to `less`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the tools you mention call the C function isatty() which determines whether the relevant file descriptor (in this case stdout) of the process is going to a terminal.

If the output is for a terminal they enable colour, highlighting, make beep noises or whatever other features they think a human user would derive value from. If there isn't a terminal, they output raw text for the digestion of other tools.

When you write

```
grep -v "Dogs" list-of-animals | less
```

The isatty() call from grep runs on the file descriptor leading to the pipe, not your terminal. So it returns zero, errno is set to EINVAL or ENOTTY and grep outputs raw text suitable for less.

Answer (score 10):

Use `less -R` or add `LESS=-R` to the environment.  This requests that `less` pass some escape sequences (such as color) to the terminal instead of printing them as normal characters.

Answer (score 8):

grep and friends detect whether output is to a terminal. When piped to less, it isn't, so they disable colouring.

Look at `isatty` to check whether the output is a terminal.

Note that I sometimes find this quite annoying because **I *want* less to display the colors**:

```
alias less='less -SR'
alias grep='grep --color=always'
```

---

Also look at [ANSIFilter](http://www.andre-simon.de/zip/download.html#ansifilter) for the reverse: to filter ANSI escapes out of existing streams (you can also use it to produce HTML, RTF, and possibly other formats from them)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to allow less to pass colour escape sequences to the terminal:

`&gt; echo -e "\033[31m -- Hello World! -- \033[m" | less -R`

...or if you want to pass all escape sequences:

`&gt; echo -e "\033[31m -- Hello World! -- \033[m" | less -r`

Comment: +1 :-) also:  google "ansi escape codes"  , and:  http://www.linuxfocus.org/English/May2004/article335.shtml