# How are escape-sequences removed when redirecting program output?

Tags: ansi-escape

Many Linux programs with a command line interface use different escape sequences to color the text. For example, you can color text red by displaying the sequence `0x1B[31m` in front of it. When I do this in my programs, if I redirect the program output to a file, it will contain these sequences. However, if, for example, I redirect the output of the `git status` command to a file, it will contain only text -- no escape sequences.

For example, here is my Pascal program:

```
program ColorPrinting;
begin
    writeln(#27'[31m', 'Hello, world!', #27'[0m')
end.
```

If its output is redirected to a file, it will contain escape sequences, which is to be expected:

```
$ ./test | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 33 31 6d 48 65 6c  6c 6f 2c 20 77 6f 72 6c  |.[31mHello, worl|
00000010  64 21 1b 5b 30 6d 0a                              |d!.[0m.|
00000017
```

However, if I do the same for the Git program (which turns staged changes green and unstaged changes red), its output is plain text:

```
$ git status -s > git-status.out && hexdump -C git-status.out
00000000  41 20 20 2e 67 69 74 69  67 6e 6f 72 65 0a 3f 3f  |A  .gitignore.??|
00000010  20 67 69 74 2d 73 74 61  74 75 73 2e 6f 75 74 0a  | git-status.out.|
00000020  3f 3f 20 74 65 73 74 2e  6f 75 74 0a 3f 3f 20 74  |?? test.out.?? t|
00000030  65 73 74 2e 70 61 73 0a                           |est.pas.|
00000038
```

If I understand correctly, programs don't know what happens to their output at all -- the Bash shell does the redirection itself. Then how does it work? Does Bash automatically clean some programs' output stream from escape sequences? Or is it something else?

Comment: Which specific program language are you using? There are solutions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087775/how-do-i-detect-when-output-is-being-redirected, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021916/how-do-i-check-if-my-delphi-console-app-is-redirected-to-a-file-or-pipe or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453220/how-to-detect-if-console-in-stdin-has-been-redirected

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it was possible to find out from the program if the standard output stream is redirected to a file... So, apparently, Git checks this fact, and disables escape sequences if it redirects to a file. Thank you, @Progman!

Comment: This answers your question: [bash - color escapes codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220256/bash-color-escapes-codes)